# How can I send a single message targeted to all my applications in C#?

Tags: c#, tcp

I've been looking into using TCP to send a message over the network.

My current situation is that I have multiple instances of a single application running on a computer. I want to send out a single TCP message and let all the applications receive the message and act upon it.

All I've been able to find examples where there was 1 sender and 1 receiver. I wan't to just send a TCP message up into the network and let all the listening application receive the same message.

I've tried to use [this guide](http://www.csharp-examples.net/socket-send-receive/) but it does not seem to work with multiple receivers either.

Can anyone point me into the right direction to a guide that does what I described here above or maybe post some example?

EDIT: All I am trying to sends is a string of 10 characters, maybe there is also another way to send/receive something like that?

Comment: @Adriano I'm checking this out right now...

Comment: Can't you use UDP with a local broadcast?

Comment: Personally, I'd be using a pre-existing hub for this. Maybe redis pub/sub - that is really trivial to setup (i.e. zero configuration, zero registration - just `"publish channel_name message"`)

Comment: UDP broadcasting sounds like the protocol I need. Thanks for the suggestions so far. I'll look into it.

Comment: How about multicast MSMQ?  Check out this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588377/using-multicast-queues-in-system-messaging-and-msmq-3-0

Comment: This URL has a very simple sample of how to use UDP. http://www.prodigyproductionsllc.com/articles/programming/write-a-udp-client-and-server-with-c/

Comment: You could look at a service bus which will handle pub/sub as suggested by Marc Gravell.  Most support msmq out-of-the-box.  My FOSS service bus is here: http://shuttle.codeplex.com/ but you could go with something like NServiceBus or Mass Transit also.

Comment: UDP is not what you are looking for if you want to have a reliable network communication. It is missing error - delivery checking and retry on fail (what TCP has). But if you are working only locally on a single interface or do not care if messages will indeed be received, then go for it :)

Comment: The problem with UDP is that I have all my applications running on one machine. When trying to broadcast a UDP to all my applications it still only comes in once trough the network and only one random application will pick it up, leaving the rest of the applications in the dark.

Comment: @MarcGravell's suggestion is worth a look: [redis](http://redis.io/)

Comment: Umm... doesn't every TCP connection require a separate thread on the server side? I.e., if you have 5 tcp clients (each with a single connection to the server), you *need* 5 threads to service those clients on the server. Then it's just a simple matter of propagating the message through each of those threads... am I'm on a totally wrong tangent here??? I guess the other sane answer is UDP, but delivery is not guaranteed, so hopefully we're dealing with high-volume messaging (where one or two dropped messages don't really matter in the scale of things)...

Comment: @Pieter888, what you need is the SignalR, it will push your messages to all open client applications. look at my posted answer with references.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Shared Memory in C# to implement your requirement.
Let me explain a simple solution:
Ex:

1. Create a mapped file (with a specific name, say "XXX"),

   - It will create an array in bytes in memory,
   - Set the first byte is zero (0) or value something that you can define your own. (this byte will determine incoming message)
2. If one application wants to send message to others:

   - Write data (converted to bytes array using UTF-8 or any encoding) to memory array from the third element (index = 2)
   - Set the first byte (index =0) is 1
   - Set second byte to a random value (why do I use this byte? I will explain below.)
3. On the receiving side, they also open mapped file with the same name "XXX"

   - They need to trigger on first byte to detect incoming message. You can use Timer (with interval can be 500 miliseconds) to check that byte
   - If first byte is 1 -> it has incoming message, then read data from third element (from index 2)
4. You can now receive messages from other applications, but there is a small problem:

   - in the next trigger, the application still continues treating it like  there is a new incoming message.
   - So at this time, you need to read value of second (randomised) byte and store it as a backup for comparison in next trigger.
   - That is a real new incoming message if backup id is not equal to new id

Hope this explains how you can solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send message to all application instances, you may look at `SignalR`.

There are several posts that do introduce this framework:

- [Asynchronous scalable web applications with real-time persistent long-running connections with SignalR](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx)
- [Tutorial: Getting Started with SignalR (C#)](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)
- [ASP.NET MVC 3 Real Time Collaborative Apps with SignalR](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=780)

Answer (score 0):

Probably dumb but simple and possible.. and when abstracted through a clean interface probably a good start: choose a shared directory for the applications, write files containing the messages into this directory and use a FileWatcher to listen for changes in the directory.

Once your applications needs rise, replace the interfaces implementation with one that uses MSMQ or something similarly enterprisey.

Another simple solution would be shared memory / [memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx). The API is included in the .NET framework since v4. You'll have to manually do the read/write synchronization though.

Answer (score 0):

Are these GUI applications?  If yes, you could use `SendMessage` or `PostMessage` with a destination of `HWND_BROADCAST`. (although this will only let you send a pair of numbers, not a "string")

More complex, but designed exactly for this purpose, is a [mailslot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> Mailslots, on the other hand, are a simple way for a process to broadcast messages to multiple processes